# How to use AsyncTask method outside

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am checking server available or not with AsyncTask class and its working fine with below code

```
 class AsyncServerOnlineCheck extends AsyncTask {
    boolean isReachable;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

        isReachable = NetworkCheck.isReachable(SplashsActivity.this);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        if (isReachable) {
            new DownloadLatestData().execute();
            Toast.makeText(SplashsActivity.this, "Server is online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (database.isDataBaseCreated()) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashsActivity.this, "Server is offline", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            } else {
                connectionerror();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want use isReachable condition in other method called connectionerror. Both is in same activity. connectionerror is like below

```
public void connectionerror() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashsActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("Error!");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Connection Lost ! Try Again");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Retry",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (downloadLatestDataStatus != null) {
                        downloadLatestDataStatus.clear();
                    }
                    if (NetworkCheck.isInternetAvailable(SplashsActivity.this)) {
                        new DownloadLatestData().execute();
                    } else {
                        connectionerror();
                    }
                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

You can see one condition in connectionerror method like below

```
if (NetworkCheck.isInternetAvailable(SplashsActivity.this)) {
                        new DownloadLatestData().execute();
                    }
```

**instead this condition for network check, I want use isReachable from AsyncTask....How can I do it ?**

Comment: Change `isReachable` as class variable of the Activity instead of `AsyncServerOnlineCheck`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solved via hire freelancer for fix it. He have done like below in alert dialogue

```
 new AsyncServerOnlineCheck().execute();
```

Thanks all friends !!